# Can we perform windows authentication with React js (Client side) and .Net6 (Backend)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, windows-authentication

I have to implement windows authentication with reactjs and dotnet core api.
I have tried but my api method is authorize so im unble to call it from react it giving me 401 error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.
[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RDvQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld06Z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7f1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOpJL.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you post your program.cs code?